# AutoMapper - Map source list to a destination array

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am trying to map a source list to a destination array using AutoMapper.

Source classes

```cs
public class ReservationSource
{
    public Travel TravelSource { get; set; }

    public string SeqNo { get; set; }
}

public class Travel
{
    public string TravelId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Trip> Trips { get; set; }
}

public class Trip
{
    public string  TrainNumber { get; set; }
    public string  Arrival { get; set; }
}
```

Destination classes

```cs
public class ReservationDestination 
{
    public Route[] TravelDest { get; set; }
    public string SeqNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Route
{
    public string SequNumber { get; set; }
    public string RouteId { get; set; }
}

private static route[] GetRoutes(ICollection<Trip> trips)
{
    List<route> routeList = new List<route>();

    foreach (var trip trips)
    {
        var route = new route
        {
            SequNumber = trip.trainNumber

        };
        routeList.Add(route);
    }
    return routeList.ToArray();
}
```

Map configuration

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<ReservationSource, ReservationDestination>()

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<ReservationSource, ReservationDestination>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SeqNumber, o => o.MapFrom(src => SeqNo))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.TravelDest, o => o.MapFrom(src => GetRoutes(src)));
});
```

This is what I have tried, here I would like to eliminate the `GetRoutes` method where I will do a manual map using a `foreach` loop. Is it possible to use any other way without a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add mapping for `Trip` and `Route` classes.

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Trip, Route>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SequNumber, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.TrainNumber));
```

> Complete Mapping Configuration

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{       
    cfg.CreateMap<Trip, Route>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SequNumber, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.TrainNumber));
            
    cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<ReservationSource, ReservationDestination>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SeqNumber, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.SeqNo))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.TravelDest, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.TravelSource.Trips));
});
```

---

```cs
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        
var source = new ReservationSource
{
    SeqNo = "Seq001",
    TravelSource = new Travel
    {
        TravelId = "1",
        Trips = new List<Trip>
        {
            new Trip { TrainNumber = "A0001" },
            new Trip { TrainNumber = "B0001" }
        }
    }
};
        
var destination = mapper.Map<ReservationSource, ReservationDestination>(source);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(destination));
```

[Sample Program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y3485F)

> Output

```json
{"TravelDest":[{"SequNumber":"A0001","RouteId":null},{"SequNumber":"B0001","RouteId":null}],"SeqNumber":"Seq001"}
```

---

### References

[Lists and Arrays - AutoMapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html)

Comment: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nClient -> partners[]   .... i get this error , here the field is not specified and ll the properties are string on both source and destination

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any `partners[]`  from your models. Perhaps try to provide a minimal, reproducible example so I can check on it. Thanks.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bzp9H7  @Yung Shan I have added the sample code here ..I am trying to eliminate the manual mapping here.

Comment: I have added the sample code here

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late. I see there are quite a lot of changes in code compared to the previous code. The answer is written based on Post Owner's provided question. You can edit the question to specify and provide more detail for the question **within the scope**. Now your question is more like another question that is not relevant to the current question. I will suggest you post another question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks alot @Yong Shun.  Had created a new question here .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70198472/automapper-with-complex-object-mapping-structure